# Find the range of the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-\lfloor x \rfloor} }$

Tags: calculus, functions

> Find the range of the function $$f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-\lfloor x \rfloor} }$$

**My try :**

I know that $1-\lfloor x \rfloor >0$ So $\lfloor x \rfloor < 1  
  \ ; x <1$ now what ?

Comment: @AjayMishra . I want  range of a function . $R_f$

Comment: I pointed out the type, see you spelling of range.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of this function is $(-\infty,1)$ and Range is $(-\infty, 1)$

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is a positive integer and $x\in [-n, -n+1)$, then $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+n}}$. This is a half open line segment that starts at 
$\left(-n, \dfrac{-n}{\sqrt{1+n}}\right)$ and approaches 
$\left(-n+1, \dfrac{-n+1}{\sqrt{1+n}} \right)$.

For integers $n \ge 0$, note that 
$\lim_{x \uparrow -n}f(x) 
   = \dfrac{-n}{\sqrt n} 
   > \dfrac{-n}{\sqrt{n+1}}
   = \lim_{x \downarrow -n}f(x)
$

Thus the strictly increasing intervals  $f[-n, -n+1)$ and $f[-n+1, -n+2)$ overlap. It follows that the range of $f$ is $(-\infty, 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: When $\sqrt{1-\lfloor x\rfloor}$ equal to $0$, $f(x)$ is undefined. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I want range of function $f$ no domain .